# How to print a new line in Eclipse's debugging expression view?

Tags: java, string, eclipse, debugging

When debugging in Eclipse you can add custom expressions which evaluate at runtime.

E.g. you can add the expression `new String ("first line\nsecond line");`.

However, the value output by eclipse is *"error during the evaluation: String literal is not properly closed"* then.

Using `new String ("first line\\nsecond line");` instead doesn't help, because it gives `first line\\nsecond line`.

How can I make it output

```
first line
second line
```

i.e. how can I make Eclipse's debugging expression view print new lines?

Comment: Does it? In the single line view to the right of the expression, it does escape characters again, but in the Detail Pane, it shows a line break. Likewise, `System.out.append("first line\\nsecond line")` produces an output with newline in the console. Btw, what’s the point of wrapping the string with `new String(…)`?

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I didn't take a closer look at the Detail Pane